# How can cooperation be encouraged in and after a game jam?

Tags: project-management

The trouble is that with game jams sometimes loads of people participate, but at the end they say "Right! Bye!" and you never hear from them again. If a cooperative element was introduced, the reward from the jam would not only be a game, but a new friend to create games with.

How do you go around implementing such a design without causing lots of people to drop out?

Comment: You're asking more about fostering cooperation between the participants *after* the project is completed, right? Not some kind of cooperative gameplay element in the project itself?

Comment: Yup, its in the project itself.

Comment: Are you running the game jam?  Or a participant in it?  And can you just re-state whether you're trying to put a cooperative element into the **jam** or into a **game** made during the jam?  I'm really confused about exactly what question we're meant to be answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're not going to be able to force people to stick together after a game jam, but there's a few ways you can help. Some of these suggestions are for local jams, and some are for online only jams (and some are both)

First, get the participants to exchange contact information (names, emails, phone numbers, social security numbers (not actually social security numbers)). This will at least allow people to look up their teammates in the future if they want to collaborate again. This is also pretty easy to do.

Second, if it's a local Jam, organize game developer meetings in the future, so people can keep those connections fresh, and hopefully gain even more of them.

Finally, if it's an online Jam, establishing a year-round presence through a website, forum, and/or chat room will help keep those connections alive. For instance, Ludum Dare has an IRC chat room that is active all through the year, though it becomes filled with tons of new people during each event.

Comment: Also, simply asking "What to stay in touch to work on other projects?" might work.